# Faster way to split way big file in to smaller files?

Tags: linux, shell, file, scripting

I have a small file which is about 6.5 GB and I tried to split it into files of size 5MB each using `split -d -line--bytes=5MB`. It took me over 6 minutes to split this file.
I have files over 1TB.
Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: Question is: what is the speed determining aspect? Could that be the disk drive? If so, then the answer is: get a faster disk...

Comment: Tag [tag:batch-file] is Windows-related, so please rethink the tags you applied!

Answer (score 3):

Faster than a tool specifically designed to do this kind of job? Doesn't sound likely in the general case. However, there are a few things you may be able to do:

- Save the output files to a different physical storage unit. This avoids reading and writing data to the same disk at the same time, allowing more uninterrupted processing.
- If the record size is static you can use `--bytes` to avoid the processing overhead of dealing with full lines.

Comment: Thanks!
But I need full lines so that words or rows in case of csv don't get cut in between